# Undefined value when populating table in View(JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I have js function to get speedlimits from google api

Here is code

```
function getSpeedData() {
//Getting dates from dates inputs and imei
var start = $('#startDate').val();
var stop = $('#endDate').val();
var imei = parseInt($('#selectVehicles').val());


//Converting to needed format
var newstart = moment(start, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var newstop = moment(stop, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");


//Getting data from back-end
var roadsapikey = "**********";
var dburl = $('#getData').data('request-url');
var path = 'path= ';
var model = {
    start: newstart,
    end: newstop,
    imei: imei
};
$.ajax({
    url: dburl,
    dataType: 'json',

    type: 'GET',
    data: model,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.length !== 0) {
            speeddata = data;
            for (var i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
                path = "path=" + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + ',' + speeddata[i].Longitude2;
                var googleurl = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?"
                    + path + "&key=" + roadsapikey;
                $.ajax({
                    url: googleurl,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) {
                        speedlimits = data;
                        for (var i = 0; i < speedlimits.speedLimits.length; i++) {
                            speedobject.push({
                                speedlimits: speedlimits.speedLimits[i].speedLimit
                            });
                            speeddata.forEach((item, index) => Object.assign(item, speedobject[index]));

                        }


                    }

                });
            }
            console.log(speeddata);
            for (i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
                $('#speeddata').append('<tr>' + '<td id="imei">' + speeddata[i].Imei + '</td>' +
                    '<td id="lat">' + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + '</td>' +
                    '<td id="lng">' + speeddata[i].Longitude2 + '</td>' +
                    '<td id="speed">' + speeddata[i].Speed + '</td>' +
                    '<td id="speedlimit">' + speeddata[i].speedlimits + '</td>' + '</tr>');
            }
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

}

At first step, I get values from db. After this for every value I get lat and lng and creating path in for loop and sending requests to google api and getting response. From this response I get speedLimit property and writing those properties to new array. After this I merging arrays.

This I have in console after merging

[Screen of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EjYU.png)

After merging I need to create table (only data) and populate it with values.

This is this part of code

```
 for (i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
                $('#speeddata').append('<tr>' + '<td id="imei">' + speeddata[i].Imei + '</td>' +
                    '<td id="lat">' + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + '</td>' +
                    '<td id="lng">' + speeddata[i].Longitude2 + '</td>' +
                    '<td id="speed">' + speeddata[i].Speed + '</td>' +
                    '<td id="speedlimit">' + speeddata[i].speedlimits + '</td>' + '</tr>');
            }
```

But I have this in View

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7j3f.png)

Where is my mistake? Properties seems to be correct.

Thank's for help.

Comment: Why minusing post?

Comment: That's strange! Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Nope I don't have any errors@HamzaAbdaoui

Comment: In the console, please develop a row of the array and post a picture ?

Comment: I found problem. If I set `async:false` to 2 `ajax` call, all okay@HamzaAbdaoui

Comment: @Yevhen don't use `async:false` in ajax request. This causes the entire page to wait for an answer including UI. [Synchronous ajax request is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Answer (score 0):

You should create the array in second ajax success fn. The speedlimit property is undefined at the moment when you create string.

Like this:

```
    ...
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.length !== 0) {
            speeddata = data;
            for (var i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
                path = "path=" + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + ',' + speeddata[i].Longitude2;
                var googleurl = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?"
                    + path + "&key=" + roadsapikey;
                $.ajax({
                    url: googleurl,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) {
                        speedlimits = data;
                        for (i = 0; i < speeddata.length; i++) {
                            $('#speeddata').append('<tr>' + '<td id="imei">' + speeddata[i].Imei + '</td>' +
                                '<td id="lat">' + speeddata[i].Latitude2 + '</td>' +
                                '<td id="lng">' + speeddata[i].Longitude2 + '</td>' +
                                '<td id="speed">' + speeddata[i].Speed + '</td>' +
                                '<td id="speedlimit">' + speedlimits.speedLimits[i].speedlimit + '</td>' + '</tr>');
                        }       
                    }

                });
            }

        }
    }
    ...
```

`console.log` show the final state of value. It shows not the state at the time of the call. 
Use `console.dir` if you want to see state of value at the moment of call